# Xamarin Picker Binding from nested classes

Tags: xamarin

I am calling an API that returns nested classes (example below) and I am struggling to bind these to a Picker.

Is it possible to bind them nested classes to a picker as is? or do I need to somehow add them to a IList?

```
<Picker Title="Select a Currency" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrencyClass}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding currencyName}"/>
```

```
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Currencies _CurrencyClass;
        public Currencies CurrencyClass 
        { 
            get { return _CurrencyClass;  } 
            set 
            {
                _CurrencyClass = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

This is a cut of the class they get desterilized too

```
public class Currencies
    {

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Results results { get; set; }
        }

        public class Results
        {
            public XCD XCD { get; set; }
            public EUR EUR { get; set; }

         }
        public class XCD
        {
            public string currencyName { get; set; }
            public string currencySymbol { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }

        public class EUR
        {
            public string currencyName { get; set; }
            public string currencySymbol { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

And this a cut of the json I am receiving.

```
{
"results": {     
     "XCD": {
          "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
          "currencySymbol": "$",
          "id": "XCD"
     },
     "EUR": {
          "currencyName": "Euro",
          "currencySymbol": "€",
          "id": "EUR"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think u can use ItemDisplayBinding={Binding EUR.currentName} and your item source would be ItemSourceBinding= {Binding Currencies.result}

Comment: But I need to display all currency names, not just EUR.
Also it says "Binding: CurrencyConverterVW.Currencies can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.IList'"

Comment: right because the EUR Class should be of type List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a work around for what I was aiming to achieve, this may not be a direct answer to my question but it is a solution for my issue.

I ended up just deserializing the JSON differently into a list of a Currency and then binding easily like you normally would.

```
    class Currency
{
    public string currencyName { get; set; }
    public string currencySymbol { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

and how I deserialized it to fit in that class here, I parsed the JSON into  a JObject and then for each child of each child I deserialize it into my Currency class.

```
        List<Currency> cList = new List<Currency>();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlAPI);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
        var children = jo.SelectToken("results").Children();
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            var childrenOfChild = child.Children();
            foreach(var c in childrenOfChild)
            {
                cList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c)));
            }
        }
```